# Vim Formatprg PAR to justify comments with Date Stamp

Tags: vim, formatting, par

I am using PAR paragraph reformatter. It is an incredible tool to be used with Vim. I am having a situation where, I have a comment that has date, developer initials and the comment message. I want to align (justified) it using Par, so that it maintains the indentation for date and initials. Is that possible?

Here is what I have:

[image]

**Here is what it does when I try:**

> set formatprg=par\ r80j

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

**Thank you.**

Comment: Please, don't use screen shots when you can copy and paste the text. Also, would avoid us having to re-type to play with it.

Comment: Sorry. It makes sense...I will add as a text from now on so that its easy to try it out.

Comment: No problem. Use the code mode or check the editing faq. Thanks! Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  don't  recommend setting  this  as  the standard  formatting  program
options, unless this  is your standard way of writing  any text. So here
is a filter version, better for single uses:

```
:%!par 80p25dhj
```

I'm assuming you want a 80 final width and justified text. Remove `j` or
change `80` if needed. Also, the width  of the prefix is a guess. Please
check it:

```
;  2012/12/12  AB    Lorem ipsum ....
^                   ^
|-------------------| This width in the original text
```

I guessed 25 but use a correct number.

Comment: **OMG**....This is incredible...This is exactly what I wanted..It works like a charm.... Thank you so much....sidyll

Comment: @Cricrazy Happy that it worked! :-D This utility par is very powerful and complex, so is the manual. I recommend exploring it when you have the time, it is useful in the long run. Also, if the question solves your problem, please mark it as accepted answer to help future viewers here to know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using par on daily basis.  I've been planning to understand WTF all those concepts in par's manual _actually_ mean for maybe 10 years now -- and I'm a mathematician.  But you know what, the author has been putting off rewriting of said manual for even longer.  Yay for learning by doing -- saves you from _understanding_ what you're doing. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura lol Yes, and it really needs the rewrite. Interesting that this program was first written in the year I was born, and since then not to have  a proper documentation is thus a life-time wait :-D Anyway, I think it even says this, but the manual is really a explanation of how it works, not its usage. I didn't understand many parts until I opened the code and then "ah, this is what he means". The good part is that we can see how a brilliant programmer mind works. The bad part is we may not understand _it at all_ if we don't spend the time to understand _it all_, the whole process.